# Make Duplicity list files to be backed up?

Tags: linux, backup, bash, rsync, duplicity

When using `--dry-run` with rsync it can list the files that will be backed up. But when I with duplicity do

```
duplicity --dry-run --name pchome --encrypt-sign-key xxx --include $HOME/Desktop --exclude '**' $HOME file:///mnt/backup
```

it just gives the statistics.

**Question**

How can I get duplicity to list the changes (copy/dalete) it will preform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the verbosity of output. According to [duplicity man](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html):

```
       --verbosity level, -vlevel
          Specify output verbosity level (log level).  Named levels and corresponding values
          are 0 Error, 2 Warning, 4 Notice (default), 8 Info, 9 Debug (noisiest).
          level may also be
          a character: e, w, n, i, d
          a word: error, warning, notice, info, debug

          The options -v4, -vn and -vnotice are functionally equivalent, as are the
          mixed/upper-case versions -vN, -vNotice and -vNOTICE.
```

`--verbosity info` worked for me